# Linguistic consultants

Tags: terminology

I'm writing an article that benefitted from a native-speaking linguistic consultant. I have several linguistic consultants, but this gal in particular really did a lot. She even helped train the other linguistic consultants. How should I refer to her? "Chief Linguistic Consultant" seems a bit inappropriate (since she is a Native American). I asked her for her preference and she has none, she doesn't even mind "chief" -- but I want to keep things professional and keep up appearances.

What's the standard way to refer to such individuals in the literature?

Thanks.

Comment: How about main or primary consultant?

Comment: You could even add her as a co-author.

Comment: If she did that much, she should be a co-author. Why not, after all? Science is done by teams, and articles routinely have multiple authors. Best practice is inclusion.

Comment: Yes, sometimes coauthor of course! But not always...